# Dynamically displaying data in arraylist

Tags: android, multithreading, parse-platform

In my application I'm trying to display data that is in a `ArrayList`. The user is able to go to the next and previous element in my ArrayList, and the data in that position would be displayed. My problem is, that I don't know how to display the data AS it comes in from Parse.com. For example, what condition would I check on the UI thread to check if it was loaded into the `ArrayList` so I can display it? I'm assuming while the first element is not loaded, I would just display a progressbar.

Also, how would the UI thread be notified when ALL of the rows were retrieved and can be displayed? Would I set a global variable?

2 queries that might be applicable from Parse.com:

```
// This is used to get a list of objects from the query
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.whereEqualTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
// This one is used to get a single object as opposed to a list of objects
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // Here I would add this to the list
      // object will be your game score
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

Now, I probably want to use the query that gets the `List<ParseObject>`, because I'm getting the data from an entire column, not just a single object. But, if that's the case, then isn't that impossible to know when each individual element is done? The callback would just let you know when ALL of the list is finished loading. I was thinking the second one could be possible, because I would know when each individual one is finished, but how would I know which row I didn't already query from that column. One way around this is to do a selection condition, but this seems pretty intense with calculation. I've done things like this, but only for `ListViews` and `Cursors`.

My initial thought was to just display a loading dialog progress bar, but that is no different than just blocking the UI thread.

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, using a progress dialog is different than blocking the UI thread: the user can dismiss the dialog (and you'd have to deal with that properly in your code.)  Blocking on the UI thread means no processing of input of any kind (including Android lifecycle callbacks) and the chance for ANR.

If you wrap your `ArrayList` in an `Adapter` and your UI component (i.e. `ListView`) is fed from that adapter, you can freely (protect as necessary) add data to your `ArrayList`, just notify the view of the change by calling the `BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method.  This will cause the UI to update its display of the data.  Couple this with a `Loader` or other mechanism to do your data transfers in the background and it will achieve what you want.

Comment: In terms of UI, I really can't use a ListView, it wouldn't really make much sense in my situation. Or, are you saying that I can just use BaseAdapter for an array list, without the need of a ListView?

Comment: ListView is just one example of a view which can be driven by an adapter.  There are others, it is really up to you.  You could also implement your own data set observer and trigger your UI updates via that mechanism.

Comment: Awesome, that solves one part, but I still have a problem with needing objects to be called back one at a time and not all at once, how would I solve that?

Comment: or, are you saying just put up a progress dialog, and let them wait it out?

Comment: It's completely up to you how to handle it with respect to your desired user experience.  If you want the user to see updates as they are happening, you'd have to be notified of each load and the UI redrawn accordingly.

Comment: No problem, hopefully it'll help with your current issues and direction.  Best of luck!